Opera GX glitched my Big Sur
I downloaded Opera GX and used the installer when Opera GX finished and opened I couldn't press F3 or F4, and my Dock disappeared as well as my wallpaper.
I've tried relaunching Finder with Opt+Cmd+Esc but it didn't work! Have I been hacked or downloaded a virus? I locked the screen and that just showed the default wallpaper and when I went back in and it was still the same. Everything works after a restart.
What can be learned from this event?
